# Why do Java decompilers generate code with gotos?

Tags: java, goto

After decompiling a .jar file, I saw this line in the resulting Java code:

```
for (Iterator i = val.getparts(); i.hasNext(); goto 135)
```

What does this mean? Why does decompiled Java code contain `goto` statements if `goto` doesn't compile?

Comment: Did you decompile the jar?

Comment: yes, i used decompiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most decompilers don't consider the fact that `goto` is invalid in Java source files. It appears in jars and classfiles because compilers use it to implement the following at [bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode) level:

- `if-else` statements
- Loops
- Switches
- `try-catch-finally` blocks